# Convert String to application/octet-stream Java

Tags: java, json, inputstream

I am writing a server side application with embed jetty that receives some request from a third party client. The client uploads some small files to the server. But I am astonished to see that the client does not upload file data as application/octet-stream instead it uploads a json as application/json that includes all the metadata about the file and in a field all the data as a string. for an simple example

> {
>       "_id": "fruit",
>       "name": "fruit",
>       "_shasum": "4954f1f8b4a8cbf9ea6b675face476f030cf7fbb",
>       "tarball": "http://localhost:8585/fruit/-/fruit-2.0.0.tgz",
>       "_attachments": {
>       "fruit-2.0.0.tgz": {
>         "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
>         "data": "mF6/622swKoG0kbVvS8qCyF5r48CuyiCO60Mcl/LnOyufzAEZ5xxxhn/IT4DO4Fr4QAMAAA=",
>         "length": 545
>       }   } }

Now the question is **how can i convert that to .tgz file?** I can not change the client so i have to work with this.

Comment: You can't convert that to the file. Either you're trying to receive the file wrong, or the client is broken and sending bad data.

Comment: I dont think so. when i am uploading i am getting only one request thats the data i am getting. So no error in file. And as the client uploads data i think client is also not broken. And the same client works with its deafult server with same technique - which is written is js.

Comment: Oh right, I missed the base64 encoded data. I thought you were using HTTP. Well if that's the whole data, you can just decode and save it. You know how to use Base64, right?

Comment: Yeah I do. I also forgot about Base64 Encoding. And thats solves the problem.. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just got the String using a JSON parser

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded);
```